# Replacing TensorFlow Saver with Checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I've been using TensorFlow's Saver class to save model parameters, but that class is going away in TensorFlow 2, so I need to replace it with Checkpoint.  I can't figure out how to do that.  All the examples in the documentation for Checkpoint assume you're saving a `tf.keras.Model`.  I'm not using Keras, so that doesn't apply.

Saver just takes a list of variables to save, so that's what I'm starting from.  How do I pass that to Checkpoint?  It expects you to pass every checkpointable object as a named argument.  I was hoping I could just say `variables=[var1, var2, ...]`, but it doesn't accept lists.  I could pass every variable as a separate argument, but what do I use as the names?  The variable names?  That defeats the whole purpose of checkpoint, which is to be more robust by not depending on variable names.  What is the intended way of writing checkpoints in code that doesn't use Keras?

Comment: Please define 'I'm not using Keras'. checkpoint.save can handle keras Model class, and you don't have to use model.fit, but a custom loop instead. It'd be helpful if you provide some code

Comment: I mean that no instance of tf.keras.Model appears anywhere in the code.  It creates instances of tf.Variable for parameters, uses standard math operators to compute the outputs and loss function, and calls minimize() on the optimizer to get the training op which it executes directly.

Comment: AFAIK, in eager mode variables are 'stored' in objects, like tf.keras.Model. You can either create custom class that will inherit from mode(as stated in the docs), or store variable manually(also described in docs). Will this suffice for an answer?

Comment: Where in the docs does it describe storing variables manually?  Also, the code needs to work both in graph mode and eager mode.

Comment: It's described here https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/checkpoints#list_and_dictionary_tracking. And what do you mean by graph mode, this `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution` ?

Comment: I mean anything annotated with @tf.function.  See https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/autograph.

Comment: This works the same way, but you'll need to manually provide variables, like this `checkpoint.listed = [a, b]`